# Flask Upload File Not Found

Tags: python, flask

I want to make a file uploader using Python, Flask, and HTML. If I upload a file I get:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL
>   manually please check your spelling and try again.

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for, render_template
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

UPLOAD_FOLDER = './user/Tom/Files/'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'])

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER


def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
if request.method == ['POST']:
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        flash('Geen Bestand')
        return redirect(request.url)
    file = request.files['file']
    if file.filename == '':
        flash('Geen Bestand')
        return redirect(request.url)
    if not os.path.exists("user/Tom/Files/"):
        os.makedirs("user/Tom/Files/")
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file',
                                filename=filename))
return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == ('__main__'):
    app.run(debug=True, port=8000)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload a File!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="user/Tom/Files/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" id="customFile" name="file">
      <input type="submit" name="Upload" value="Upload">
    </form>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the action and the value

Now i have this:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" id="customFile" name="file">
  <input type="submit" name="Upload">
</form>
```

But now it stay on de index.html but doesnt upload it to /user/Tom/Files/ ?